# How To test the exit status, and do something in Makefile

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to do this ..... and this is how my Makefile look like

```
.PHONY: run
SHELL := /bin/tcsh

run:
    md5sum -c md; \
        if ($$?==0) then \
            echo "PASS" \
        else \
            echo "FAIL" \
        endif
```

But i got this error.

```
if: Badly formed number.
make: *** [run] Error 1
```

Is what I'm doing correct? Or is there a better way of doing that in a Makefile?

Answer (score 5):

Basically, you should simply not, ever, use `csh` (or `tcsh`) for writing makefile rules.  Write the rule using POSIX shell:

```
.PHONY: run
run:
        md5sum -c md; \
            if [ $$? -eq 0 ]; then \
                echo "PASS"; \
            else \
                echo "FAIL"; \
            fi
```

Comment: but if i don't use SHELL=/bin/tcsh, then my recipe which has 'source ~/.cshrc' will fail. How should I work around that?

Comment: You shouldn't do that.  This means that everyone who uses your  makefile must use csh (which is, to be honest, not a good shell) and must set some random stuff in their shell config file.  Why would you want to do that?  Anyway, csh is broken for use in makefiles, because csh is broken for use as a scripting language and makefile recipes are basically little scripts.  Also, csh does some broken things with pipes which means if you use it as `SHELL` then parallel builds will not work.

Comment: For more information read the famous http://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/misc/csh.html and consider how a makefile recipe is sent to the shell as a single command on a single line (all newlines removed), then re-read the above paying particular attention to the different ways csh treats statements containing newlines and those that don't.